# How can I get rid of `let` in Core?

Tags: haskell, optimization

I have a function that is called frequently in an internal loop. It looks like this:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as SV

newtype Timedelta = Timedelta Double

cklsLogDens :: SV.Vector Double -> Timedelta -> Double -> Double -> Double
cklsLogDens p (Timedelta dt) x0 x1 = if si <= 0 then -1e50 else c - 0.5*((x1-mu)/sd)^2 
  where
    al  = p `SV.unsafeIndex` 0
    be  = p `SV.unsafeIndex` 1
    si  = p `SV.unsafeIndex` 2
    xi  = p `SV.unsafeIndex` 3
    sdt = sqrt dt
    mu  = x0 + (al + be*x0)*dt
    sd  = si * (x0 ** xi) * sdt
    c   = sd `seq` -0.5 * log (2*pi*sd^2)
```

(Data.Vector.Storable is used because this function needs to work on data from a C function later)

GHC has optimized this very nicely (all variables and ops are primitives as far as I can tell), but looking at core, there is one `let` that is still inside of (what was) the body of the function. I have read [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/faster.html) (and somewhere else I don't remember) that 'lets' allocate lazy thunks and can thus be bad for performance in tight loops. Can I get rid of it? If it's possible, I would prefer not to convert my function into 20 case statements, but if that is too much to ask I'll accept.

Here is the Core:

```
$wloop_s4Li [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: GHC.Prim.Double#
     -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Double#
[LclId, Arity=3, Str=DmdType LLL]
$wloop_s4Li =
  \ (ww_X4OR :: GHC.Prim.Double#)
    (ww1_X4OW :: GHC.Prim.Int#)
    (ww2_X4P1 :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
    case GHC.Prim.<# ww1_X4OW ww2_X4P1 of _ {
      GHC.Types.False -> ww_X4OR;
      GHC.Types.True ->
        case GHC.Prim.<=## x_a4tg 0.0 of _ {
          GHC.Types.False ->
            case GHC.Prim.indexDoubleArray#
                   rb2_a4rT (GHC.Prim.+# rb_a4rR (GHC.Prim.-# ww1_X4OW 1))
            of wild17_X4xM { __DEFAULT ->

            let {
      ----  ^^^^ want to get rid off this! 
      ----
      ----
              ipv1_X2S8 [Dmd=Just L] :: GHC.Prim.Double#
              [LclId, Str=DmdType]
              ipv1_X2S8 =
                GHC.Prim.*##
                  (GHC.Prim.*## x_a4tg (GHC.Prim.**## wild17_X4xM y_a3BN))
                  (GHC.Prim.sqrtDouble# tpl1_B3) } in
            case GHC.Prim.logDouble#
                   (GHC.Prim.*##
                      6.283185307179586 (GHC.Prim.*## ipv1_X2S8 ipv1_X2S8))
            of wild18_X3Gn { __DEFAULT ->
            case GHC.Prim.indexDoubleArray#
                   rb2_a4rT (GHC.Prim.+# rb_a4rR ww1_X4OW)
            of wild19_X4AY { __DEFAULT ->
            case GHC.Prim./##
                   (GHC.Prim.-##
                      wild19_X4AY
                      (GHC.Prim.+##
                         wild17_X4xM
                         (GHC.Prim.*##
                            (GHC.Prim.+##
                               x1_X3GA (GHC.Prim.*## x2_X3cb wild17_X4xM))
                            tpl1_B3)))
                   ipv1_X2S8
            of wild20_X3x8 { __DEFAULT ->
            $wloop_s4Li
              (GHC.Prim.+##
                 ww_X4OR
                 (GHC.Prim.-##
                    (GHC.Prim.negateDouble# (GHC.Prim.*## 0.5 wild18_X3Gn))
                    (GHC.Prim.*##
                       0.5 (GHC.Prim.*## wild20_X3x8 wild20_X3x8))))
              (GHC.Prim.+# ww1_X4OW 1)
              ww2_X4P1
            }
            }
            }
            };
          GHC.Types.True ->
            $wloop_s4Li
              (GHC.Prim.+## ww_X4OR -1.0e50)
              (GHC.Prim.+# ww1_X4OW 1)
              ww2_X4P1
        }
    }; }
```

(Yes, of course, since you must ask, I am spending waaay too much time on premature optimization...)

Here is the current version with NOINLINE

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as SV
 
newtype Timedelta = Timedelta Double
 
cklsLogDens :: SV.Vector Double -> Timedelta -> Double -> Double -> Double
{-# NOINLINE cklsLogDens #-}
cklsLogDens p (Timedelta dt) x0 x1 = si `seq` (if si <= 0 then -1e50 else (sd `seq` (c - 0.5*((x1-mu)/sd)^2)))
  where
    al  = p `SV.unsafeIndex` 0
    be  = p `SV.unsafeIndex` 1
    si  = p `SV.unsafeIndex` 2
    xi  = p `SV.unsafeIndex` 3
    sdt = sqrt dt
    mu  = x0 + (al + be*x0)*dt
    sd  = si * (x0 ** xi) * sdt
    c   = sd `seq` (-0.5 * log (2*pi*sd^2))
    
main = putStrLn . show $ cklsLogDens SV.empty (Timedelta 0.1) 0.1 0.15
```

Corresponding Core snippet:

```
Main.cklsLogDens [InlPrag=NOINLINE]
  :: Data.Vector.Storable.Vector GHC.Types.Double
     -> Main.Timedelta
     -> GHC.Types.Double
     -> GHC.Types.Double
     -> GHC.Types.Double
[GblId, Arity=4, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=DmdType U(ALL)LLL]
Main.cklsLogDens =
  \ (p_atw :: Data.Vector.Storable.Vector GHC.Types.Double)
    (ds_dVa :: Main.Timedelta)
    (x0_aty :: GHC.Types.Double)
    (x1_atz :: GHC.Types.Double) ->
    case p_atw
    of _ { Data.Vector.Storable.Vector rb_a2ml rb1_a2mm rb2_a2mn ->
    case GHC.Prim.readDoubleOffAddr#
           @ GHC.Prim.RealWorld rb1_a2mm 2 GHC.Prim.realWorld#
    of _ { (# s2_a2nH, x_a2nI #) ->
    case GHC.Prim.touch#
           @ GHC.ForeignPtr.ForeignPtrContents rb2_a2mn s2_a2nH
    of _ { __DEFAULT ->
    case GHC.Prim.<=## x_a2nI 0.0 of _ {
      GHC.Types.False ->
        case x0_aty of _ { GHC.Types.D# x2_a13d ->
        case GHC.Prim.readDoubleOffAddr#
               @ GHC.Prim.RealWorld rb1_a2mm 3 GHC.Prim.realWorld#
        of _ { (# s1_X2oB, x3_X2oD #) ->
        case GHC.Prim.touch#
               @ GHC.ForeignPtr.ForeignPtrContents rb2_a2mn s1_X2oB
        of _ { __DEFAULT ->
        case ds_dVa
             `cast` (Main.NTCo:Timedelta :: Main.Timedelta ~# GHC.Types.Double)
        of _ { GHC.Types.D# x4_a13m ->
        let {
   --- ^^^^ want to get rid of this!
   ---
          ipv_sYP [Dmd=Just L] :: GHC.Prim.Double#
          [LclId, Str=DmdType]
          ipv_sYP =
            GHC.Prim.*##
              (GHC.Prim.*## x_a2nI (GHC.Prim.**## x2_a13d x3_X2oD))
              (GHC.Prim.sqrtDouble# x4_a13m) } in
        case x1_atz of _ { GHC.Types.D# x5_X14E ->
        case GHC.Prim.readDoubleOffAddr#
               @ GHC.Prim.RealWorld rb1_a2mm 0 GHC.Prim.realWorld#
        of _ { (# s3_X2p2, x6_X2p4 #) ->
        case GHC.Prim.touch#
               @ GHC.ForeignPtr.ForeignPtrContents rb2_a2mn s3_X2p2
        of _ { __DEFAULT ->
        case GHC.Prim.readDoubleOffAddr#
               @ GHC.Prim.RealWorld rb1_a2mm 1 GHC.Prim.realWorld#
        of _ { (# s4_X2pi, x7_X2pk #) ->
        case GHC.Prim.touch#
               @ GHC.ForeignPtr.ForeignPtrContents rb2_a2mn s4_X2pi
        of _ { __DEFAULT ->
        case GHC.Prim.logDouble#
               (GHC.Prim.*## 6.283185307179586 (GHC.Prim.*## ipv_sYP ipv_sYP))
        of wild9_a13D { __DEFAULT ->
        case GHC.Prim./##
               (GHC.Prim.-##
                  x5_X14E
                  (GHC.Prim.+##
                     x2_a13d
                     (GHC.Prim.*##
                        (GHC.Prim.+## x6_X2p4 (GHC.Prim.*## x7_X2pk x2_a13d)) x4_a13m)))
               ipv_sYP
        of wild10_a13O { __DEFAULT ->
        GHC.Types.D#
          (GHC.Prim.-##
             (GHC.Prim.negateDouble# (GHC.Prim.*## 0.5 wild9_a13D))
             (GHC.Prim.*## 0.5 (GHC.Prim.*## wild10_a13O wild10_a13O)))
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        };
      GHC.Types.True -> lvl_r2v7
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't moving `sd \`seq\`` to the `else` branch help? The thunk you're pointing at seems to disappear for me then.

Comment: It doesn't for me. I have played around with `seq` a bit, (maybe not enough) but `if si <= 0 -1e50 else sd \`seq\` c - ...` doesn't do it form me

Comment: I hope you mean `sd \`seq\` (c - ...)` ;) There's still a thunk popping up for me, but it's a completely different one.

Comment: Changing the first line of the function to `cklsLogDens p (Timedelta dt) x0 x1 = si \`seq\` (if si <= 0 then -1e50 else (sd \`seq\` (c - 0.5*((x1-mu)/sd)^2)))` and setting it to NOINLINE (to avoid inlining into my `main`) gives me a Core devoid of any let.

Comment: Hm, for me it doesn't. I'll edit the example so we'll be talking about the same thing ...

Comment: Ah. It didn't happen for me without `-O2`. The Core is *smaller* without it.

Comment: I did try BangPatterns, too, still no luck... What are you guys using for generating the core? I use the function provided by the emacs haskell extension. If you post an answer with how you did it I'll happily accept it.

Comment: The optimizer seems really intent on keeping it this way. When I copy-paste the Core, rewrite it to Haskell, and change the let statement to something that looks like the case statement that binds `wild10_a13O`, it just chucks it back into a thunk.

Comment: My *guess* is that it's related to the demand analysis making a bad call. I assume the `[Dmd=Just L]` annotation for `sd` (a.k.a. `ipv1_X2S8` a.k.a. `ipv_sYP`) means that the analysis has concluded that the `in`-part of the `let` expression is not strict in `sd`. The optimizer takes this conclusion and puts `sd` in a thunk. Why GHC isn't impressed by the `\`seq\`` magic is beyond me, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using ghc-7.6.1, I get no difference between `-O` and `-O2`, and neither do any `seq`s or bang-patterns make a difference.The `let` remains in the core.

But I doubt that `let` is really harmful, it binds a primitive value, not a boxed one, and that value is used in three places thereafter. Besides, in the produced assembly, I can find no hint of a lazy thunk (but since my knowledge of assembly is rather limited, don't take this as gospel).

I can get rid of the `let` by introducing a case-branch,

```
cklsLogDens p (Timedelta dt) x0 x1
    = case p `SV.unsafeIndex` 2 of
        si | si <= 0   -> -1e50
           | otherwise ->
                let al  = p `SV.unsafeIndex` 0
                    be  = p `SV.unsafeIndex` 1
                    xi  = p `SV.unsafeIndex` 3
                    sdt = sqrt dt
                    mu  = x0 + (al + be*x0)*dt
                in case si*(x0**xi)*sdt of
                     0   -> 0
                     sd -> -0.5*log (2*pi*sd^2) - 0.5*((x1-mu)/sd)^2
```

which only produces `case`s in the core. Since `sd` should never be 0, in a loop, even a mediocre branch predictor should make that branch essentially free.

However, I doubt whether that would actually improve performance. The comparison to 0 costs a register, the assembly produced by the original needs less indirect addressing and can keep more values in the registers when they are needed.

Comment: Well, so-so. It makes the value of `sd` needed immediately, so it gets a `case` in the core. But as I wrote, I rather expect that to slow the thing down than speed it up.

Comment: I wonder if maybe the cmm/llvm backend takes care of the let in the original definition?  Too lazy to check the asm now...

Answer (score 12):

Daniel is right - the `let` in question does not, in fact, allocate a thunk. That would actually be impossible, as primitive types such as `Double#` don't have a heap representation. These `let`s are in fact converted to `case` expressions before conversion to STG (which is where the "`let` = allocation" rule actually holds) in the so-called core preparation phase. See the comment on this topic in [CorePrep.lhs](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/coreSyn/CorePrep.lhs#L76).

Here's again the Core from before preparation (`-ddump-simpl`):

```
    let {
      ipv_sPL [Dmd=Just L] :: GHC.Prim.Double#
      ipv_sPL =
        GHC.Prim.*##
          (GHC.Prim.*## x_a160 (GHC.Prim.**## x1_a11G x2_X17h))
          (GHC.Prim.sqrtDouble# x3_a11P) } in [...]
```

And here's after (`-ddump-prep`):

```
    case GHC.Prim.sqrtDouble# x3_s1aU of sat_s1cB { __DEFAULT ->
    case GHC.Prim.**## x1_s1aQ x2_s1aR of sat_s1cC { __DEFAULT ->
    case GHC.Prim.*## x_s1aC sat_s1cC of sat_s1cD { __DEFAULT ->
    case GHC.Prim.*## sat_s1cD sat_s1cB of ipv_s1aW [Dmd=Just L] { __DEFAULT ->
```

So there is actually no heap allocation whatsoever.

On the other hand, note that core preparation also explicitly wraps every single application into a `let` or `case` statement, producing pretty verbose code. That's why `-ddump-simpl` is probably considered the default for looking at Core, even though its performance model is actually slightly more surprising.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! This is the confirmation (as to whether the `let` allocates or not) I was looking for. I'll be checking the 'prepped' core in the future. Thanks!